# LootLocker - How to show local rank

Tags: unity-game-engine, leaderboard

In my game, I am able to show the GlobalRank, however, I would also like to show the position of a player in Ranking according to the global results.

So in the bottom line, there should be the local (on this device) results.

Basically, on the left bottom corner, I want to get the RANK from the LootLocker, but I am struggling to get the rank...

```
IEnumerator ShowScores()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    

        LootLockerSDKManager.GetScoreList(ID, maxScores, (response) =>
        {

            if (response.success)
            {
                LootLockerLeaderboardMember[] scores = response.items;
                for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
                {
                    playerNames[i].text     =   (scores[i].member_id        +"");
                    playerScores[i].text    =   (scores[i].score            +"");
                    playerRank[i].text      =   (scores[i].rank             + "");

                    //Rank of the localPlayer
                    Rank.text               =   (scores["here_Should_Be_This_Player_ID"].rank + "");


                    LootLockerSDKManager.GetPlayerName

                    // Entries[i].text = (scores[i].rank + ".       " + scores[i].score + ".      " + scores[i].member_id);
                }
                if (scores.Length < maxScores)
                {
                    for (int i = scores.Length; i < maxScores; i++)
                    {
                       // Entries[i].text = (i + 1).ToString() + ".  none";
                    }
                }



            }


            else
            {

            }

        });



    

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with the LootLocker support team
Step 1 - load LootLocker and get the resonse
Step 2 - load the rank and get the resonse2
Step 3 - use the "Response2.rank from the LootLocker
Rank.text = (response2.rank + "");

````
        string playerIdentifier = "PlayerNameRecordOnThisDevice";
        LootLockerSDKManager.StartSession(playerIdentifier, (response) =>
        {
            if (response.success)
            {
                
                Debug.Log("session with LootLocker started");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("failed to start sessions" + response.Error);
            }


            LootLockerSDKManager.GetMemberRank(ID, playerIdentifier, (response2) =>
            {
                if (response2.statusCode == 200)
                {
                    Debug.Log("GetMemberRank Successful");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("GetMemberRank failed: " + response2.Error);
                }

                Rank.text = (response2.rank + "");
            });

        }); ```
````